# 'task_done() called too many times' AsyncIO Error

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am getting this error each time I run my code (below). I have 3 example URL's to scrape, but it will always try to scrape a 4th time, meaning there is a phantom task in the queue which in turn triggers the 'task_done() called too many times' error.

If I change the number of consumers to handle the tasks in the queue to 3, then it will produce 3 'task_done() called too many times' errors - so obviously I am going wrong with the queue/concurrency.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession, TCPConnector, ClientTimeout
from typing import Optional

urls = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.google.com/']
method = "GET"

# Consumer coroutine - takes a task from queue for consumption
async def consume(queue, session, event, len_urls, results):
    max_retries = 0  # Maximum number of retries = 0
    retries = {}  # Dictionary to track the number of retries for each URL
    while True:
        try:
            status: Optional[int] = 0
            body: Optional[str] = None

            # Exctract from queue
            index, url = await queue.get()
            # print(url)

            async with session.request(method, url) as response:
                body = await response.text()
                status = int(response.status)
                print(status)

        except Exception as e:
            error = str(getattr(e, "message", e))
            if isinstance(e, aiohttp.ClientResponseError):
                status = e.status
            print(status, " error: ", error)

        finally:
            try:
                print("Tasks in queue:", queue.qsize())
                print(f"Status: {status}")
                if (not status == 200):
                    if url not in retries:
                        retries[url] = 0  # Initialize the number of retries for the URL
                    if retries[url] < max_retries:
                        print("Retrying")
                        # Add task back to queue
                        print("Tasks in queue before adding:", queue.qsize())
                        await queue.put((index, url))
                        print("Tasks in queue after adding:", queue.qsize())
                        retries[url] += 1
                    else:
                        print("Max retries exceeded. Skipping URL.")

                else:
                    results.append({
                        "url": url,
                        "status": status,
                        # "body": body
                    })
            except Exception as e_fin:
                print(f"Error in finally block - {str(e_fin)}")
            finally:
                try:
                    # Remove task from queue
                    queue.task_done()
                    if len(results) >= len_urls:
                        event.set()  # Set the event when all tasks are completed
                        break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

# Where the magic happens
async def main():
    timeout = ClientTimeout(total=None, sock_connect=60, sock_read=60)
    # Close underlying sockets after connection releasing - otherwise IP isn't rotated for retries
    conn = TCPConnector(ssl=False, force_close=True)
    len_urls = len(urls)
    # Create a Queue object.
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    # Create an Event object.
    event = asyncio.Event()
    # List of tasks
    consumer = []
    results = []

    # Context manager for session
    async with ClientSession(connector=conn, timeout=timeout, raise_for_status=True) as session:

        for index, url in enumerate(urls):
            queue.put_nowait((index, str(url)))

        # Consumer tasks to handle tasks in queue
        for i in range(0):
            # Create task and add to consumer list
            consumer.append(asyncio.create_task(consume(queue, session, event, len_urls, results)))

        # Wait for count of queue to = tasks added to queue (this will triggger th event)
        await queue.join()
        print("Number of completed tasks:", len(results))
        print("Expected number of URLs:", len_urls)

        # Cancel all remaining worker tasks, nothing left to consume
        for task in consumer:
            task.cancel()
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = asyncio.run(main())
    # print(m)
```

Thanks for your help.